# cannot execute specific powershell script *edit

Tags: powershell

as i was trying to execute a powershell script (neo4j community) i was promted with a note, that it was possibly unsafe and whether i really wanted to execute it. there were some options which i sadly dont remember, but i know that i chose option e. ever since i cannot execute this file. the error is:

```
.\neo4j.ps1 : File
C:\Users\schme\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-08342466-f47c-45e8-9428-ed818fcafefd\bin\neo4j.ps1 cannot be
loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\neo4j.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

As powershell scripts are restricted by default, i tried `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` which yielded no positive result. however i can execute powershell scripts which i wrote myself.
does anyone know how i can tackle this problem?
i am on windows 11 and i already checked the gpedit.msc for any guidelines, but havent found any which would correspond to this problem. i also tried resetting all guidelines through the commandline which also didnt help.

Comment: Sounds like some application control measure (WDAC, ASR or SRP) is configured on your machine. Go talk to your IT department

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share 
 `get-item ../neo4j.ps1 -stream *`. Then, you could run `Unblock-File ../neo4j.ps1` if you see the `Zone.Identifier` alternate data stream on your file **and** if you are on the Windows or macOS platform…

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i have removed all student and company accounts from my machine and there are no other users and i am an admin, but it still throws the same error

Comment: @JosefZ I ran `get-item ../neo4j.psi -stream *` but i do not see any `Zone.Identifier`  stream in the output.

Comment: @JosefZ and i am on a windows machine